# How do I associate a shortcut key combination to a macro in Word 2007?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-word-2007, macros

I've created a macro that inserts a reference to a table
When I did the macro, I configured the access to this macro through a button. But, now I want to change it to use the keyboard instead of icons.
Does anyone know how to change from icon to a keyboard access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look here: http://www.brighthub.com/computing/windows-platform/articles/19475.aspx
The 2nd part of this post is the perfect answer to your question.

For more info about assigning shortcuts in Word, look here:

- http://wordprocessing.about.com/od/workingwithmacro1/l/blmacrokey.htm
- http://word.mvps.org/faqs/customization/asgncmdormacrotohotkey.htm

Answer (score 0):

The easiest approach is to create a new macro with the required keyboard shortcut, move the content from your old macro to the new one, and delete the old one.