# How to assign a MS Word macro to a hotkey?

Tags: microsoft-word, macros, microsoft-word-2007, hotkeys

I've created a macro in MS Word 2007, but to run it, it seems I have to open Developer > Macros > Run each time. Surely there is a way to run this over and over with a hotkey, but how?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to configure a hotkey/shortcut to activate a macro in Outlook 2007?](http://superuser.com/questions/171885/how-to-configure-a-hotkey-shortcut-to-activate-a-macro-in-outlook-2007), [How do I associate a shortcut key combination to a macro in Word 2007?](http://superuser.com/questions/332462/how-do-i-associate-a-shortcut-key-combination-to-a-macro-in-word-2007)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Choose `Customize` on the `Tools` menu, then click `Keyboard`. In the `Categories` list, choose either `All Commands` or `Macros`, as appropriate. In the list on the right, choose a command or macro then enter a key combination in the space provided.

Before clicking `Assign`, look where it says `currently assigned to`, and make sure you are not about to reassign a really useful shortcut. Also before clicking `Assign`, select the template where you want the assignment to be stored.

Click `Assign`, then `Close`. Hold the `Shift` key down and select `File + Save All`, to save your changes to the template.

Answer (score 2):

Click the office button, go to *Word Options*.

In word options, go to *Customize* and at the bottom is a *keyboard shortcuts: customize* button.

In the left box scroll down to "macros" and select the macro in the right box to assign it a new shortcut key.